# AbpSession.UserId is null right after login

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm trying to implement a command line app using my `MyApp.Core`, `MyApp.Application` and `MyApp.EntityFramework` modules that are working perfectly with a `MyApp.Web` module.

The problem with the `MyApp.Console` app is the login: once I execute the login, `AbpSession` values are still `null`, so when I invoke a service protected by any permission, it returns me that the user is not authenticated.

Here is the code:

```
var result = await _logInManager.LoginAsync("myuser", "mypassword "mytenant", true);
if (result.Result != AbpLoginResultType.Success) throw new AbpAuthorizationException(result.Result.ToString());
// *** WHY AbpSession.TenantId and AbpSession.UserId are still null here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61801051/752004) I decided to create my `IAbpSession` implementation.

For doing it I simply cloned the `TestAbpSession` available [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.TestBase/TestBase/Runtime/Session/TestAbpSession.cs) in a dirty `MyAbpSession`. Then I configured it as default `IAbpSession` in MyApp.Console module.

Here it is the code:

```
[DependsOn(
    typeof(MyAppApplicationModule),
    typeof(MyAppDataModule))]
public class MyConsoleAppModule : AbpModule {

    public override void PreInitialize() {
        // set my IAbpSession implementation
        Configuration.IocManager.RegisterIfNot<IAbpSession, MyAbpSession>(DependencyLifeStyle.Singleton);
    }

    public override void Initialize() {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

And in the application class:

```
public class AppMain : ITransientDependency {

    public MyAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }

    public AppMain() {
        // What to set here?
        //AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
    }


    // code to login
    private async Task Login(userName: string, password: string, tenantName: string) {
        var result = await _logInManager.LoginAsync(username, password, tenantName, false);
        if (result.Result != AbpLoginResultType.Success) throw new AbpAuthorizationException(result.Result.ToString());
        AbpSession.TenantId = result.User.TenantId;
        AbpSession.UserId = result.User.Id;
    }

    public async Task Run(AppOptions options) {
        await Login(options.userName, options.password, options.TenantName)
        // my code ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ClaimsAbpSession`, the default implementation of `IAbpSession`, gets session properties from the claims of the current user's principal, which are usually set in the (web) response after you call `_signInManager.SignInAsync(...)`.

To get the `TenantId` and `UserId` right after `_logInManager.LoginAsync(...)`, you can use `loginResult.User.TenantId` and `loginResult.User.Id`.

You can also override the current session values with the logged-in user:

```cs
var loginResult = await _logInManager.LoginAsync(...);
if (loginResult.Result != AbpLoginResultType.Success) throw new AbpAuthorizationException(...)
using (AbpSession.Use(loginResult.User.TenantId, loginResult.User.Id))
{
    // AbpSession.TenantId and AbpSession.UserId now return the logged-in user's values.
}
```

Reference: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Abp-Session#overriding-current-session-values

Comment: Following your suggestion and analyzing the source code of  Abp I wrote my AbpSession By the way, I found the overall solution a bit complex for a simple login

Comment: Regarding the Use method, it is in general a good option, but not the solution for me, as I need a global AbpSession

Comment: I guess your way is sufficient for a console app. Feel free to mark your answer as accepted.